# How do I access a Rest endpoint on a scratch org?

Tags: rest, salesforcedx

I've set up a connected app and a rest endpoint on a scratch org but can't access it through either the workbench, Postman or client code. I get the following error in each case:

> 404 Not Found

response body:

```
{
        "errorCode": "NOT_FOUND",
        "message": "Could not find a match for URL"
}
```

For the code and postman approaches, I'm getting back a sessionId. It's the subsequent call to `../services/apexrest/MyEndpoint` that's failing.

The URL I'm using is the autogenerated scratch org URL

`https://xxxxxxx-xxx-XXXX-dev-ed.cs42.my.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/MyEndpoint`

I tried using `https://test.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/MyEndpoint` but get a different error:

> 400 Bad request

Is there something different about Rest endpoints on scratch orgs I need to be aware of?

Comment: I was just able to access a custom rest endpoint in a scratch org using a Session Id, so it seems to work. One question - does the org have a namespace? If so, you'd need to add that in the URL

Comment: Does the scratch org user have permission to execute that Apex class?

Comment: Thanks everyone. The URL should be as follows .../services/apexrest/<namespace>/MyEndpoint

Comment: @AidanD If you figured it out, it's legit to answer your own question to let other users with the same question find help.